# Why is my pytest selenium function skipped?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently learning how to use pytest selenium. Here is the simple function that I try to run:

```
def test_example(base_url, selenium):
    selenium.get('{0}'.format(base_url))
```

I define the base_url in pytest.ini file as followed:

```
[pytest]
base_url = http://www.facebook.com
```

And I run in linux command shell with `py.test --driver Firefox` but the function is skipped.

Here is the result:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?